# GroupBy Agg columns in Pandas with the last value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with duplicates values (same date and price), I want to add the volumes of the rows with the same date and price. I use a groupby function for this:

```
                    Price      Size

Date        
2020-04-24 16:59:35 2828.00     1
2020-04-24 16:59:35 2827.75     3
2020-04-24 16:59:35 2828.00     1
```

'

```
new = df.groupby(['Date','Price'], sort=False).agg({'Size': 'sum'})
```

The problem is that as 2828.00 appers first, the end result would be:

```
                    Price      Size

Date        
2020-04-24 16:59:35 2828.00     2
2020-04-24 16:59:35 2827.75     3
```

I want to keep the order from last to first. Desired output:

```
                    Price      Size

Date        
2020-04-24 16:59:35 2827.75     3
2020-04-24 16:59:35 2828.00     2
```

Is there any additional parameter to acomplish this? Thank you

Comment: do you need : `df.groupby(['Date','Price'], sort=False).agg({'Size': 'sum'}).sort_index(level=1)` ? what do you mean by `last to first` ?

Comment: There are repeated prices for the same date, if a price x appers first then a y price and then x again the function keep the first x and add the volumen of the second x. I want that from the last (second x) adds the volumen of the fist x. This way the closing price of the date will be acurrated, otherwise is not keeping the same closing as in the original DataFrame.